# How to save an image in a folder in ASP.NET Core MVC that comes from Xamarin.Forms Android?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to save an image that comes from Xamarin forms Android but the method `Post` doesn't get the image, but the image reaches the page.

Xamarin code:

```
await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();               

if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsPickPhotoSupported)
{
    await DisplayAlert("No pick photo", "no pick photo available", "OK");
}

_mediaFile = await CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync();

if (_mediaFile == null) 
    return;

lblStatus.Text = _mediaFile.Path;

var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
content.Add(new StreamContent(_mediaFile.GetStream()), "\"file\"",
                $"\"{_mediaFile.Path}\"");

var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var uploadServiceBaseAddress = "http://url/api/Files/Upload";

var httpResponseMessage = await httpClient.PostAsync(uploadServiceBaseAddress, content);
lblStatus.Text = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

ASP.NET Core MVC / C# code:

```
[Route("api/Files/Upload")]
public async Task<string> Post(List<IFormFile> files)
{
        try
        {
            foreach (var formFile in files)
            {
                if (formFile.Length > 0)
                {
                    var fileName = formFile.FileName.Split('\\').LastOrDefault().Split('/').LastOrDefault();
                    var filePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "~/Uploads/", fileName);
                 
                    using (var stream = System.IO.File.Create(filePath))
                    {
                        await formFile.CopyToAsync(stream);
                    }

                    return "/Uploads/" + fileName;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            return exception.Message;
        }

        return "no files";
}
```

In my mobile app return "no files", so the image is not saved in the folder.

Does someone know why that is?

Thank you very much!

Comment: This is not the same question because now i have a different problem...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I leave my code in case it helps someone. I just had to change these lines

```
[Route("api/Files/Upload")]
    public async Task<string> Post()
    {
        try
        {
            var fileName = this.Request.Form.Files[0].FileName.Split('\\').LastOrDefault().Split('/').LastOrDefault();
            var filePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"wwwroot\Uploads\", fileName);

            using (var stream = System.IO.File.Create(filePath))
            {
                        await this.Request.Form.Files[0].CopyToAsync(stream);
            }
            return "/Uploads/" + fileName;

        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            return exception.Message;
        }
        return "no files";
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).